# Error when try to use EntityFramework 7 + SQLite on OSX

Tags: macos, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dnx

I'm try to use EntityFramework 7 + SQLite on a sample App with .Net Core on a Mac OSX environment. I have installed the Mono 4.0.2 and .Net Version Manager, this is my "dnvm list" command result:

```
   1.0.0-beta7-12274    coreclr x64  darwin
   1.0.0-beta6          mono         linux/darwin    default
   1.0.0-beta7-12274    mono         linux/darwin
*  1.0.0-beta7-12275    mono         linux/darwin
```

When a try to execute some EntityFramework.Command, the follow problem occurs:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryInformation' from assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

The full stack is:

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryInformation' from assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Execute (System.String startupProject, System.Func`1 invoke) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.AddMigration (System.String name, System.String context, System.String startupProject) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program+<>c__DisplayClass10_1.<Main>b__7 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost host, System.String applicationName, System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at dnx.host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName targetFramework) [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 1):

`ILibraryInformation` was renamed recently, and the DNX beta7 you're using probably includes this change: make sure to also reference recent beta7 packages in your `project.json` file.

You can use the wildcard to reference the latest version:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Sqlite": "7.0.0-*"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pinpoint, I put on another answer here in this question a detailed information, could you check ??

Answer (score 0):

Because of project renames, nightly builds are currently broken. To use just beta6, you may need to try these steps:

- Remove `~/.dnx/packages`. Some of these may contain a mix of post- and pre-rename references.
- Ensure you are not using the nightly nuget feed (myget.org)
- `dnvm use 1.0.0-beta6`
- Make sure you are using `"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta6"` and `"EntityFramework.Sqlite": "7.0.0-beta6"` in project.json.
- Follow the [Workarounds](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/osx.html#workarounds) in the Getting Started on OS X guide.